# Entity Framework 7 Reverse Engineering ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

I have been trying to migrate my database into web app model using EF7 _4.

Couple things I realized is that the syntax/approach how to configure particular entities has been changed.

Normally you generate POCO classes by using EF Power Tools (EF6), which generates entity types and entity map as configuration. All clean, all works.

My question is, **does someone experience how to do it with EF7?**

From the msdn blog I have found here about [Entity Framework 7 Beta 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/04/29/entity-framework-and-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx)

the features for reverse engineering are still on dev phase. "**An early preview of reverse engineering a model from a database**".

Comment: what more needs to be said than what you posted? it's still in development, the feature isn't there, so nobody can make a post telling you how to use a feature that doesn't exist yet.  EF7 is not in a stable state for normal projects at the moment, as they state regularly.

Comment: It is release candidate, I assume that fundamental features are implemented already.

Comment: @stenly No, it is not. The page you linked says: "still very much a preview." There is nothing about EF7 being RC.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sorry, not RC but beta. If you start your first proj with EF7 and mvc 6 (VS2015) you have everything set from model/data perspective to do you seeding, migration, etc. EF Power Tools can generate POCO classes - separated utility. Similar feature should be in EF7 soon but meanwhile if someone has came across on something similar what could generate POCO in same entity declaration as start proj template does, was my question.

Comment: @stenly At this point, you could always use Power Tools for EF6 and copy the classes. You will however have to redo the mapping yourself and any many-to-many relations you have will have to create the middle table to make it a many-to-one and one-to-many. It might not be exactly seamless since EF7 is quite different than EF6, but it would be a start.

Comment: @Nick-ACNB thanks, I solved it like you proposed

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838 this work??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something that will get you on your way. As you know its still all beta and this is a little complex but the best we have at the moment.

http://stoutcloud.com/geek-out-entity-framework-7/geek-ef7-reverse-engineering-first-look/

Just some commands to help along the way, since they changed a little since it changed to DNX. You can go into the command prompt or Powershell.

First make sure you install the relevant entity framework packages (as described in the above article). Make sure you get the latest and not beta1. I have found it needs to match the beta number of the DNX. E.g. if you get DNX beta5 you need to download the nightly builds of EF of beta5.

Nightly build NuGet package source for reference: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2

Don't forget to add this to your project.json

```
"commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }
```

Now on to the commands

```
dnvm install -r coreclr latest
```

(or just use clr if you don't want the coreClr)

Go into the project directory then type

```
dnu restore

dnx . ef

dnx . ef revEng Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Databasename;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

I have heard they are working on a GUI for this so we will just have to wait and see.

Comment: Why the downvote? The link provides a working method on ASP.NET vNext to reverse engineer a database using EF7 and KRE. Did I miss something? There are no point and click tools about just yet, it is the best we have until they put a UI on top of it.

Comment: no idea who gave you downvote but this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: FYI - Microsoft have renamed KRE to DNX, so the commands in the article needs changing slightly - http://jameschambers.com/2015/05/project-k-dnvm-dnx-dnu-and-entity-framework-7-for-bonus-points/

Comment: Can't figure out how to pass the connection string parameter in the latest...  trying dnx ef dbcontext scaffold -connection='sql connection string' but it doesn't recognize the -connection parameter .. how are you supposed to pass arguments into the thing??

Comment: hi @ClaySmith - Sounds like a new question, post a new question on StackOverflow, feel free to link to it from here in the comments if you want me to have a look at it.

Comment: @Adam sure why not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377984/entity-framwork-7-reverse-engineer-from-existing-db-code-first . Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be updated in rc1-final http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model

Comment: @AdamPedley but still unable to find revEng command, i have posted a question too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896038/entity-framwork-7-0-0-rc1-final-reverse-engineer-from-existing-db-database-first