# Entity Framwork 7 reverse engineer from existing db "code first"

Tags: dnx, entity-framework-core

I can't figure out how to pass the connection string parameter in the latest version of dnx... trying

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold -connection='sql connection string'
```

but it doesn't recognize the -connection parameter .. how are you supposed to pass arguments into the thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "sql connection string" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

Comment: Well that works after adding to my project.json dependencies "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-*", however when I try to specify and output directory with -o I get "System.Exception: TODO: Error: unrecognized option '-o'"

Comment: I think that option is coming in beta 8

Comment: In version 7.0.0-rc1-final the provider is 'EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer'.