# entity framework 7 Convert existing database tables to code first classes in asp.net mvc 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have existing database in ms sql server.

I want to get database tables as code first classes in asp.net mvc entity framework 7.

However,

If i try to add new item in project i **can not see any data item in order to add model**.

I am not sure how can i add **entity model** as **database** to **code first** by using **asp.net mvc 6 entity framework 7** ?

**Note:**

Do i have to add model in entity framework 6 project after that i have to copy converted classes to entity framework 7 project ? If it is .. i am doing in this way and this is not working for me because of mismatching old and new version of entity framework

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any help please . Do i have to add model in entity framework 6 than i have to copy tables to entity framework 7 project ? If it is .. i am doing in this way and this is not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419577/entity-framework-7-reverse-engineering-asp-net-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution below link helps me so much.

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html