# Entity Framwork 7.0.0-rc1-final reverse engineer from existing db "Database first"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, reverse-engineering, dnx

I am doing **reverse engineering** in my project. because our project we follows database first approach.

Through this command, i achieved reverse engineering but not with **RevEng** command.

```
dnx ef DbContext Scaffold "Server=databasename;Database=data;UserID=*;Password=*;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

I have tried many things but still unable to find **RevEng** command under the **ef**.

In a project, i am using

```
 "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    }
```

and

```
"dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.Relational.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",        
}
```

So how can i enable **RevEng** command in dnx, 
Help me to out !

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework RC1 is very incomplete.  There is a ton of functionality missing.  In its current state, it's almost unusable.  Besides, on the next release dnx is going away.  So probably many of the things you're figuring out now will change.  Dnx will be replaced with a new library called net or something like that.

Comment: @Client is there any reference link where I found something relevant it. Rc1 is in final, so are the changing this too?

Comment: It's just the final version of Release Candidate 1.  There's probably going to be a couple more release candidates before EF7 is released.  So there's not much if any documentation available.  I've learned most of what I know from the devs that post on GitHub.

Comment: @Client
In this link they mentioned features about ef.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap
So is this best to go with EF7 when i am using database first approach

Comment: @ClintB Generally a Microsoft "Release Candidate" is supposed to be feature complete, i.e. it was a candidate for full release, and the only additional changes generally would be things they like bugs or if they got a lot of feedback about something that was disliked.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch So to clarify, this is not a situation where we are talking about a pre-release that will later have features added to the final release.  In those terms, it's not "incomplete".  As far as the team developing EF7, my understand is it's considered feature complete.  EF6 features not included in EF7 were intended, and will not be added to the final EF7 release.  For example, no more support for EDMX. That feature is being retired.  Don't expect it to be "completed" in a final release.

Comment: @AaronLS - I was referring to the general concept of "Release Candidate" from Microsoft.  Yes, Ideally it would be feature complete, and that's supposed to be the case.  However, it seldom happens.  Let's look at the Visual Studio release candidates, where new features were still being added in RC stage, same with TFS upgrade RC's.  Sometimes Microsoft labels something as RC even when feature incomplete so the users have a go-live license.

Comment: @AaronLS - and as if to illustrate the point, it was just announced that there are major changes in the pipeline of .NET Core RC2.  From the ASP.NET standup `The most noticeable change to the structure of the project is the introduction of the Program class with the public static void Main method.  Starting with ASP.NET Core RC2, web projects are formatted and structured similar to console applications.  The Main method is the entry point for the application and boots the ASP.NET host.`

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Changes are expected during the release candidate cycle, but that is different than claiming that release candidates are generally incomplete. That claim creates a the misconception that they would expect these missing features to show up in a later RC, which is unrealistic. Yes, they make changes based on external feedback and internal discussions if deemed important enough, but they certainly weren't planned. To call it "incomplete" implies they already have a **plan** to add those features. Many of the features missing in EF7 were intended and unlikely to be added during RC

Answer (score 0):

> The command **reveng** - which was short for "**reverse engineering**". But it
>   was changed to **dbcontext scaffold** a while back. reveng no longer
>   exists. I have got the solution of question. for more go with this
>   link

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5194